# First slide of parallax scrolling ALWAYS Full screen

Tags: html, css, parallax

Product is not finished yet. :D

I'm making a parallax website for myself. Currently I have 3 sliders (home, about and contact). I would like to have the first Slide (home section) always be full screen, no matter what resolution or any kind of zooming you have.

The only way for me to accomplish this right now, is giving a height in pixels to the first slider (home). Ofcouse this wont be a full screen on some one else his screen (other resolutions). I dont really mind the other sliders heights, I just want the first slider (home) to be always fullscreen on any resolution.

Right now my home slider in the CSS has a height of 100%, so my home slider is not that big (in height), because my content in it is not much at the moment.

See the code below for what I have at the moment. HTML and CSS code. Dont mind the element tags, still needs some cleaning. :D

Anyone has a solution for this? Thanks!

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}
/* ==========================================================================
Parallax Scroll
========================================================================== */

/* Slide 1 */

#home {
  background: #000000 no-repeat center center fixed;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
/* Slide 2 */

#about {
  background: #ffffff no-repeat center center fixed;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#contact {
  background: #ffffff no-repeat center center fixed;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
/* ==========================================================================
Sections CSS
========================================================================== */

/*.loading 
{
background: url('../img/ico_loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
}

section 
{
opacity: 1;
}

.loaded section 
{
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;;
transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}*/

#brand i {
  color: #8f1c35;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center-table {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.center-tablecell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.row-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-centered {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
#text1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#text1 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #a21838;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#text2 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #a21838;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#text3 h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #a21838;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#contactme .info {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 21px;
}
#contactme .email {
  color: #a21838;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#contactme .social-media {
  color: #a21838;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  ;
}
#aboutme .study {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 21px;
}
#aboutme .me {
  color: black;
}
#aboutme .projects {
  color: #a21838;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#name #student {
  text-align: center;
}
#name h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
#student h2 {
  margin-top: 75px;
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#container-edu {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#container-edu .edu {
  color: #a21838;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
hr {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 75%;
}
/* ==========================================================================
Animations Navbar CSS
========================================================================== */

/* ==========================================================================
Bootstrap Navbar CSS
========================================================================== */

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #8f1c35;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #8f1c35;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #8f1c35;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #8f1c35;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #8f1c35;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #8f1c35;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #8f1c35;
  }
}
/* ==========================================================================
Non Mobile First
========================================================================== */

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {}
/* Small Devices, Tablets || IS VAN 250% EN HOGER ZOOM! */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #name h1 {
    font-size:42px;
  }
  #student h2 {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  #text1 h1 {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  #aboutme .study {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  #text2 h1 {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  #contactme .info {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  #text3 h1 {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
}
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #name h1 {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
}
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-sectionScroll" data-offset="230">
  <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-sectionScroll" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="brand" href="#home">FirstName <i>LastName</i></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="home">
    <div class="container center-table">
      <div class="row text-center center-tablecell">
        <div id="student">
          <h2>Student Software Developer</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="name">
          <h1>Name</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section id="about">
    <div class="container center-table">
      <div class="row text-center center-tablecell">
        <div id="aboutme">
          <div id="text1">
            <h1>ABOUT</h1>&nbsp;
            <h1 class="me">ME</h1>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <p class="study">My name is LoremIpsum.
            <br/>I am currently studying as a Software Developer at the Hogeschool Stenden in Emmen.</p>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <p class="projects">Projects</p>
        </div>

        <div id="container-projects">
          <div class="row row-centered">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-centered" style="background: black; height: 200px; width: 300px;"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-centered" style="background: black; height: 200px; width: 300px;"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-centered" style="background: black; height: 200px; width: 300px;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="container-edu">
          <p class="edu">Education</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container center-table">
      <div class="row text-center center-tablecell">
        <div id="contactme">
          <div id="text2">
            <h1>CONTACT</h1>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <p class="info">If you would like to make any contact, please see below for more information.</p>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <p class="email">Send an Email</p>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>

          <div id="social">
            <p class="social-media">Social Media</p>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: I find it quite hard to understand exactly what you're looking for. Does perhaps changing the `height: 100%` into `min-height: 100%` on the `#home` solve your issue?

Comment: Didn't solve it. I have 3 sliders. I want the first slider (home) to be always fullscreen, so 100% in height, no matter what the resolution is or how less the content in it is. If I give the height, for example 1000px, it might be a fullscreen (100% in height) on my screen, but not on yours, lets say because of the resolution difference. Sorry, I've never been good in explaining things. :D

Comment: Don't worry, explaining things is really hard I also have that issue :). I think that the `height: 100%` on the `#home` already makes it fill the entire height of the screen. Don't you like it? Or doesn't it work?

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it did not work. It fills the screen up to the content I have in it, and that's just a h1 and h2 at the moment. So it does not get the whole screen (100% in height).

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you use Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I am. Would that make a problem?

Comment: No, i was just wondering. I've converted your code into a code snippet. If it also doesn't work there I either don't understand what you want or it's perhaps a browser issue

Comment: That's what I wanted! But how did you got it working, the first slider is always in 100% height now in any resolution, isnt it?

Comment: I didn't change anything to your code I think. It could be that not all ancestors of the first slide had the height set to 100%. You might have an issue if the content becomes larger than 100%. In that case think of changing it to min-height

Comment: Strange. If you didnt change anything, why isn't it working for me then? I have tried the min-height, but no results. All other slides have their height set at 100%.

Comment: I've fixed the problem, haha, so simple. I had a div in my original code around all the sections that I did not use, I deleted it and it workde. Thanks for the help!